# Creating a Computed Column on table creation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

```
create table Sales
( 
    SalesID int identity (100000000,1) primary key,
    SaleDate datetime,
    ProductSold varchar (40) not null,
    QuantitySold int,
    SalePrice smallmoney,
    Tax as SalePrice * .13  ,
    TotalSale  as (SalePrice + Tax)   
 );
```

I am trying to get the `TotalSale` column to calculate `Saleprice` column plus `Tax`, but it says `Tax` is computed and therefore can't be used. How would I go about getting it to do such, if there was a way?

Error:

> Computed column 'Tax' in table 'Sales' is not allowed to be used in another computed-column definition.

Comment: You could write `TotalSale as SalePrice * 1.13`. But what will you do if the VAT changes?

Comment: Another possibility is to move the calculations to a [view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190174.aspx). As Sean Lange points out, history is an issue. Storing the tax and computing the `TotalSale` makes more sense.

Comment: I would argue that Tax should not be computed. It should calculated at the time of the order and stored. Not only does the computed column stink if the tax percentage changes, it will change your historical data when you modify the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

I would also advocate storing calculating and storing Tax. In either case, the reason for your error was due to the multiple use of a computed column. I've edited my `CREATE TABLE` to store Tax as `smallmoney` and compute SalesPrice + Tax for the TotalSale.

[This will help](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/04/06/sql-server-fix-error-1759-computed-column-in-table-is-not-allowed-to-be-used-in-another-computed-column-definition/).

Essentially, you cannot *define* a computed column more than once. You can do the workaround in the link, which is to "double down" on your SalePrice column use:

```
create table Sales
( 
    SalesID int identity (100000000,1) primary key,
    SaleDate datetime,
    ProductSold varchar (40) not null,
    QuantitySold int,
    SalePrice smallmoney,
    Tax smallmoney ,
    TotalSale  as (SalePrice + Tax)   
 );
```